# Не работает Unfollow

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Иду по учебнику railstutorial.ru делаю все как написано но появилась одна ошибка, кнопка follow работает а кнопка unfollow нет.

Вот код.

---

**sample_app/app/views/users/_unfollow.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user),
         html: { method: :delete },
         remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

---

**sample_app/app/views/users/_follow.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id),
         remote: true) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

---

**sample_app/app/controllers/relationships.rb**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

---

**sample_app/app/views/relationships/create.js.erb**

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

---

**sample_app/app/views/relationships/destroy.js.erb**

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>')
```

---

---

P.S Вот учебник [railstutorial.org](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/following-users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax)

P.P.S. Глава 11.2.5

---

---

Comment: В браузерной консоли при этом какие-то ошибки выводятся? В логах сервера?

Comment: @D-side   В браузерной консоли ошибок нету, работаю на виртуальной машине, через localhost:3000, где находятся логи?

Comment: Там, откуда запустили `rails server`/`rails s`.

Comment: @D-side   В логах была ошибка (не додумался посмотреть)

Comment: @D-side в user.rb была функция undollow а не unfollow спасибо за помощь и время